# How to handle exception in CompletableFuture and return Integer value

Tags: java, completable-future

I have a method like:

```
public Integer handleException(CompletableFuture<String> future)
      throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    return future
        .thenApply(Integer::parseInt)
        .handle((result, ex) -> {
          if (result != null) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, ex.getMessage());
            return null;
          } else {
            return 42;
          }
        });
}
```

I want to handle exception in my `CompletableFuture<String>`. All I want to do is logging exception error in case occurrence and return -1 and in case of no error, I want to return 1. My code seemingly works but the entire expression in the handle method is underlined with error:

[image]

I have a method either like:

```
return future
        .thenApply(Integer::parseInt)
        .exceptionally(
            s -> {
              LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "ASD");
              s.printStackTrace();
              return -1;
            })
        .get();
```

which works but supposedly this is not the best possible solution of Exception Handling and thats why I decided to use handle() method. 
I will be grateful for a suggestion of what I am doing wrong in the handle() method approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `handleException` is declared to return `Integer`, while you are trying to return `CompletableFuture<Integer>`. Probably forgot the `.get()`...